# IOS i got [UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] error

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

The error is not every time.
i had try to clean and rebuild app,but it is also.

error:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController 
    transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:], 
   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIWindowController.m:211

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
     reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from 
     <UINavigationController: 0x9190730> to <UINavigationController: 0x83a9dc0> 
     while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear
     to know the current transition has completed'

 *** First throw call stack:
 (0x213d012 0x1e85e7e 0x213ce78 0x191bf35 0x10b8d05 0xeb74f3 0xeb7777 0x10be033f   
  0xeb77b7 0x104f0 0x1e996b0 0x18c6035 0x20c0f3f 0x20c096f 0x20e3734 0x20e2f44 
  0x20e2e1b 0x36437e3 0x3643668 0xdcd65c 0x1133f2 0x25c5)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

BaseController.h:

```
 @class LoginViewController;
 @interface BaseController:UIViewController
 //...
 @end
```

BaseController.m

```
 @implement BaseController
 //...
 -(void)showLoginForm
 {
    UIViewController* loginx =(UIViewController*) [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* navx = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginx];
    [navx.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"title_bar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    //added
    //i can use @try to catch it       
    [self presentModalViewController:navx animated:YES];//<====it is error

    [loginx release];
    [navx release];
 }
```

LoginViewController:

```
 @interface LoginViewController:BaseController
 //...
 @end
```

otherViewController:
i will judge the user is login or not in this controller.if it is not login,i will call showLoginForm

```
  //@interface otherViewController:BaseController
  //......
 -(void)viewDidLoad
  {
     //make a thread to call isLogin
  }
 -(void)isLogin
  { 
      BOOL logined = YES;
      //......
      if(!logined)//i take this on MainThread,it has error also.
         [super showLoginForm];
  }
```

MainViewController:(it is the Main ViewController to show otherViewController)

```
 //@interface MainViewController:BaseController
  //......

 -(void)buttonAction
 {
     otherViewController* other = [[otherViewController alloc] init];
     UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:other];
      [self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
     //release
  }
```

so ,Who knows how this is going on?

Comment: As the error message suggests, it seems like you're attempting to present the navx navigation controller, while another controller (the otherViewController maybe?) is probably being pushed to the existing controllers stack. Can you explain a bit the workflow? What appears first, what next? I take it that your app is navigation based so there's another UINavigationController that manages your viewcontrollers' hierarchy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In otherViewController.m you should move the code that calls the isLogin method to

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This will make sure that the transition for the presentation of the otherViewController will have finished when `[self presentModalViewController:navx animated:YES];` is called.